# Installing Fedora 19 with not enough free space left

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I'm completely new to Linux, and I wanted to install Fedora 19 with my Windows 7 (dual boot).

When I go through the installation process it only shows my hard drive (not partitions) and says that there are 37 GB and 17 MB available for us and says that there is not enough space on my hard drive.

I have a 500 GB hard drive and three NTFS partitions with a lot of free space – should I resize one partition and leave the free space unallocated and then try to install Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

Solution boot your system with windows and after download "fedora 19 windows installer", follow some steps and install it.Enjoy the Linux
For more information go to below link :
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_ARM_Installer

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Guide/pt-install-info-x86.html